# CreatePeriodicTimer not updating UI when UWP app minimized

Tags: uwp

I tried updating UI with sample Date Time scenario using CreatePeriodicTimer in UWP app.

I see it works when app is in foreground, the moment it is minimized it stops firing the event.

But in Debug Mode the timer fires and UI is updated even when app is minimized, but doesn't happen in Release mode.

I need to know how it updates in minimized mode also.

```
namespace PeriodicPolling
{
    class Poller
    {
        public static Poller _instance = null;
        ThreadPoolTimer _timer = null;
        public static MainPage UpdatePage { get; set; }
        public static Poller GetInstance()
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new Poller();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
        public void StartPoll()
        {
            _timer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer(PollAndUpdateData, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }
        async void PollAndUpdateData(ThreadPoolTimer timer)
        {
            DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
            await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync
                (CoreDispatcherPriority.High,
                    new DispatchedHandler(() =>
                    {
                        UpdatePage.MyBlock.Text = dateTime.ToString();
                    }
                ));
        }
        public void StopPoll()
        {
            _timer.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that UWP apps go into [suspended mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle#app-suspend) when they are minimized:

> When the user minimizes an app Windows waits a few seconds to see
>   whether the user will switch back to it. If they do not switch back
>   within this time window, and no extended execution, background task,
>   or activity sponsored execution is active, Windows suspends the app.
>   An app is also suspended when the lock screen appears as long as no
>   extended execution session, etc. is active in that app.

This does not happen while the debugger is attached, but you can simulate this behavior using the **Debug Location** toolbar (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> and type *Debug location* or click **View** -> **Toolbars** -> **Debug Location**.

When your app is minimized, the `Application.Suspending` event is called and you can handle it to release any resources or stop your timer while the app is "asleep".

It is also possible to let the app run in full when it is minimized. More info about this can be found in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution#run-while-minimized). The best option is, however, to keep background app usage as low as possible and utilize background tasks for long-running processes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it worked. But I have a requirement to poll some API indefinitely while the app is open. But in contrast I came to know that Background tasks are for short lived operations.
Even the application trigger background task runs max for 10mins.

Kindly help me in some model in UWP where I can indefinitely poll until app is closed.

Comment: In such case the solution linked in my answer is probably the best bet - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution#run-while-minimized

Comment: I see that this ExtendedExecution suggestion that you provided will be used if we want to execute some code even after suspending state for some amount of time but not indefinitely. This is requested when app gets suspended.

But My requirement is like both during the app is active as well as suspended I should be able to query an API indefinitely and provide notifications.

Kindly help

Comment: I am afraid running code when the app is actually suspended isn't possible at all. You could run a periodic background task to check for the notifications or implement push notifications service to achieve such solution

Comment: I already reviewed these approaches. I tried periodic background task so only asked you in my first comment that it doesn't run indefinitely and 10mins is the maximum. So any solution here to run periodic background task without time limit.

Reg the push notifications service you had mentioned, I guess there should be a cloud service which sends push to WNS and then we handle in client app, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. It would be better to keep a background service running and constantly polling for notifications. Push approach is better, because the other side will wake up your background service when actually needed, which will save user's internet traffic and performance.